# How to exclude border from opacity change

Tags: html, css, transparency

I have this CSS:

```css
#name { 
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "times new roman";
}
```

however the border also has opacity set as 0.3 but I do not want the border to have opacity how do I exclude this element?

Comment: You can't. You'd probably need to remove the border on this element, wrap this element in another and set the full opacity border on the wrapper.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. `opacity` sets the opacity on the entire element. Depending on the element's actual content, you have two options:

1. Wrap the entire content in a `<div>` and apply the border to that instead.
2. If there's only text and/or a background, use `rgba` to specify the text color and/or background color/gradient instead of `opacity`.

Comment: Using RGBA works unless you wanted everything in the block to have the opacity applied (i.e. images). For that you would need to use the container method.

Comment: is rgba compatible with IE browser?

Comment: @Lukus: IE9 and up, yes. For IE8 and earlier, no. You'll need a fallback or an image.

Comment: @minitech with a fallback can I have opacity? if not how can i make a png image the fallback?

Comment: @Lukus: You could use the usual `filter: alpha(opacity=something);` and just live with the border being semitransparent, or you can use a wrapper if making it look exactly the same on every browser is crucially important.

Comment: @minitech can I use a png image as a fallback? if so how?

Comment: @Lukus: Make a 1x1 PNG image with your color and transparency as the single pixel, and set that as the `background-image`. It won't work for text, however.

Comment: @minitech filter: alpha(opacity=40); now does not work in firefox but works in IE

Comment: adding both filter and opacity work, however still not content with border. Divs are not an option as I am using jquery hint aswell.

Comment: @minitech how can I allign text in the middle within a textfield: <input name="name" type="text" id="name" style= "text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; height:21px" size="25" maxlength="300" />...does not work..

Comment: @Lukus: Ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a  container with border and the content with opacity:

```
<div id="container" style="border:1px solid #fff">
  <div id="name">
   --------
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using inline styling directives is discouraged unless you have a very spesific reason.

Comment: @fastreload it was just for example sake. everybody writes "production code" how they see fit to :)

Comment: I understand, yet considering OP is new to stackoverflow and is likely new to CSS; it is usually more helpful to keep the coding conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Change the HTML structure to:

```
<div id="name">
    <div>
       Stuff
    </div>
<div>
```

And the CSS to:

```css
#name { 
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#name div { 
    color: #a5a5a5;
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "times new roman";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container.

```css
#name {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: times new roman;
}

.op3 {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
    <div class="op3">
       <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
#name { 
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "times new roman";
    height: 50px;
}

#name:after {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
```